# Adjusting Container View's height to match height of child's subview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

[image: Embedded Tabbar Controller]

In my project I have a container view with an embeded segue to a tabbar controller where the tabbar's item views each contain only a tableview.

(in the image above the bottom UIView is the container view with the embeded segue to the tabbar and the top UIView is just some other content)

I have the above setup working properly but what I want to implement is adjusting the height of the container view to match the height of the tableview in the selected item of the tab bar.

[image: Goal]

The reasoning for this is that I would like to place more content below the container view and want the new content to be very close to the content of the container view but occasionally the tableview being displayed is only a few rows and there is a lot of unused space leftover in the container view that needs to be trimmed.

In the above image the container view is in a scroll view with the additional content, if the table the container view is displaying is smaller than anticipated the leftover space needs to be removed so there does not appear to be lots of whitespace between the table and the additional content.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to maintain a reference to each tabbar item and therefore the tables in them.

To obtain the references in `prepare(for segue: )` loop through all the `tabBar.viewControllers` and create the references there.

Once you have the reference you can obtain the heights of the tableviews by `viewController.tableView.frame.height` and whenever a tab is selected resize the container view based on the table height.